# Remove all the previous activites except home activity

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-finish

How to remove all the activities except HomeActivity.

ex:
A(HomeActivity)->B->C->D
now call B activity again removing C & D activities. I'm sending some data from D activity to B activity through intent. I have next button if i click next button then this process will be done. If I backpress then my process will be D->C->B->A

Comment: removing  mean `finish` that  `Activity` ?

Comment: While intent to another activity if I use finish method. Then how should I press backbutton and achieve D->C->B->A? So finish can't be used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're going from D->B, use  `intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`
It will close all of the other activities on top of it and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to create `static activity` variable in both C & D activity.

Just like this

```
 //create static variable
 public static CActivity cactivity;
```

then initialize this variable in `onCreate` of `Activity`.

```
  //initialization 
  cactivity=this;
```

Finish that `activity` where you want

```
// use this where you want to finish activity 
CActivity.cactivity.finish();
```

Make sure `Activity` must be running in background other wise you app will crash.

Comment: Thank you for ur valuable time. Your answer also work :)

Answer (score 1):

what I would of suggest is a not-so-smooth solution but instead of start activities for all of those replace them with a startActivityForResult, search for the result code and if it is returned from the activity (that is for you to handle of course) then call finish with all activity in the way with the result code until you reach your home activity.

Comment: Thank you for ur valuable time. Your answer also work :)